# Multiplication to formalize Microbiological Processes

Tags: microbiology

I am not from the field, but have a question regarding modeling in biology:

- I know that some processes can be modeled with the mathematical multiplication operation, and wondered if anyone could give me an example (or examples).
- Especially with regards to axonal growth and the chemical (de-)stabilization taking place which involve microtubuli and actin, I was wondering if these processes again could be formalized mathematically as multiplication of (several) variables.

I have looked through the internet but did not find anything so far,
any help is appreciated

Comment: there are mathematical models for each of these things, but i don't think they usually incorporate all possible parameters and its unlikely they are all linear (i.e. resulting from multiplication alone).

Comment: can you give me some link, some example of a multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the quick answer you asked for, too big for comments so sorry if this is not a full answer either.

This [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0437v1.pdf) is an example of cytoskeletal modelling.  the equations are not simple products (that is to say they have exponentials, derivatives and other non- multiplication operations in them).

This example reference is a [simple axonal growth model](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1366631/).  You will see derivatives being modeled as products.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: oh good - glad that worked for you.